# Regex How to match 2 any, but different characters

Tags: java

So I have a String `String s = "4433334552223";` that I would like to split into an array, on every character change (between every pair of different of characters). `String [] aRay = s.split("IDK");` I'm wanting the String array to contain `{44,3333,4,55,222,3}` after the `split()`.

I know how to do it with a loop and such, but I was just wondering if there was a simple way to do this with regex??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to match repeated characters:

```
String s = "4433334552223";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/Jjo4ag)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
String input ="4433334552223";
final String PATTERN = "(.)(\\1*)";
Matcher m =  Pattern.compile(PATTERN).matcher(input);
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
while(m.find())
{
   result.add(m.group(1)+m.group(2));
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

This produce the following output:

```
[44, 3333, 4, 55, 222, 3]
```

Comment: Oh, I see you know da wey!! Thanks for sharing:)

Comment: I hope it helped you ;-) ;-)